# SSRS 2008R2. Chart lines don't use anti-aliasing

Tags: reporting-services, charts, line, antialiasing

I created a report with the line chart in the *VS 2008*
When I design and render report in the *VS* - the lines edge look to be good, smoothed.
But as soon I deploy report to the *Reporting Service* and render it via the *Report Manager* (or by using *Report Control*) - lines edge become to be choppy.

Is there any way to turn on anti-aliasing for the chart lines?

Thank you for your answer.
Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

antialiasing line charts: i'm happy to have a solution for users of SSRS 2012 (not tested with 2008): the edges will get choppy as soon as the Chart Property | Fill | Background | Color = "no color" (transparent). If you choose a solid color for the background of the chart the lines will be smooth (antialiased).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't play about with the Anti-Aliasing settings on SSRS 2008/R2 (or 2012 for that matter).  The Anti-Aliasing option is only exposed on the Gauge control.

The [charting component in SSRS was purchased by MS](http://forums.asp.net/post/3567326.aspx) from [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/) but Microsoft made their own changes to it and for some reason or other have hidden that property from the end-user on everything but Gauge.